# Can't check that layout is not scrollable

Tags: android, android-espresso

Here my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/traderSummaryContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mcgpalette0_100"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jsonViewToolBar">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/symbolLabelTextView"
                style="@style/labelTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_default_margin"
                android:text="@string/symbol"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/symbolValueTextView"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/walletsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/traderSummaryContainer"
            tools:listitem="@layout/wallet_list_item" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

As you can see the layout "`traderSummaryContainer`" is outside of `RecyclerView` and and as result is not **scrollable**.
Nice.
Now I want to write Esrpesso's test that check this:

```
@Test
    fun traderSummaryContainer_notScroll() {
        onView(withId(R.id.traderSummaryContainer))
                .perform(scrollTo())
        fail()
}
```

But test is fail with message:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.myproject.activity.TraderDetailsActivityTest#traderSummaryContainer_notScroll' com.myproject.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll to' on view 'with id: com.myproject.debug:id/traderSummaryContainer'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:87)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:316)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:177)
```

So how I can check this?

P.S.

I use this:

```
    @Test(expected = PerformException::class)
    fun traderSummaryContainer_notScroll() {
        onView(withId(R.id.traderSummaryContainer))
                .perform(scrollTo())
    }
```

Is this a good solution?

Comment: scrollTo(), as its documentation says must be used on a child of a ScrollView, which your ConstraintLayout isn't. It's not clear what do you want to check, what do you understand by "is not scrollable"?

Comment: @Luksprog I want  to check that when user try to scroll "traderSummaryContainer" the "traderSummaryContainer" not scroll. It's fixed (not move)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good practice but I think you want to:

```
@Test
fun traderSummaryContainer_notScroll() {
    try {
        onView(withId(R.id.traderSummaryContainer)).perform(scrollTo())
        fail()
    } catch (e: PerformException) {
        // passed
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could check if `traderSummaryContainer` is not in a `ScrollView`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.traderSummaryContainer))
    .check(matches(not(isDescendantOfA(isAssignableFrom(ScrollView::class.java)))))
```